# Is there an equivalent of R’s data.table fread cmd keyword in pandas?

Tags: python, r, pandas, data.table, fread

One very useful aspect of R’s data.table reading workhorse “fread” is the “cmd” keyword with which one can programmatically build a shell command and pass it to fread to read the output of the shell command in as a data.table.

This is very powerful for interactive use as the command can be any string, e.g. an ssh one which will run on a remote host and can defer basic parsing to a simple grep/sec/awk all in one line while preventing the need for making temporary directories and files and taking additional steps to fetch remote files.

From what I can tell looking at the latest pandas docs there does not appear to be an equivalent in any of the pd.read_* methods. Is it not a feature? Is there maybe an easy equivalent people use instead?

Comment: This [blog post](https://op8867555.github.io/posts/2017-10-13-use-your-unix-toolbox-with-pandas.html) explains how to combine the subprocess module with pandas. Pandas does not have a built in module for reading in shell outputs. Another option is to work with ipython and pass the results of ur operation to pandas. [pydatatable](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable) which aims to replicate R’s datatable, offers the command option.

Comment: @sammywemmy awesome, I just tried and it seems like I can get similar succinctness by import datatable as dt followed by dt.fread(cmd=...).to_pandas()

The blog post alternative is also a good alternative, but more verbose having to create the subprocess and likely slower on large frames.

Comment: If you have found solution to the question you posted feel free to self answer it, as there might be others looking into same functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @sammywemmy pointed out there are two alternatives. The first, and slightly more verbose one than the R equivalent is to use `subprocess` like this:

```
import pandas as pd, import subprocess
with subprocess.Popen("shell_cmd", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as p:
    df = pd.read_csv(p.stdout)
```

A more efficient and less verbose alternative is to use the `datatable` package and do something like this:

```
import datatable as dt
df = dt.fread(cmd="shell_cmd").to_pandas()
```

You can also opt to work natively with the `datatable` Frame type.